# Is "How technical should a Project Manager be?" a polling question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, community-wiki

### The Problem

I stumbled across [the question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/55/4271) today when in the [review queue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review), and had some ambivalence about its current suitability. While the question as a whole seems site-relevant, it has the following problems:

1. The OP states that it's a polling question.

   > Hope you get the drift of the question. Obviously there is no right or wrong answer, just thoughts.
2. The question has 15 answers, but no accepted answer.
3. None of the answers seem [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical).

### The Problems with the Problem

1. The question itself is highly upvoted.
2. The question has been viewed (or crawled) 4,758 in the past three years.
3. Lots of other people have (historically, anyway) considered it an acceptable question.

### Close, Wikify, or Leave Alone?

I was tempted to vote to close the question with a custom close reason, citing that it is a polling question without a canonical answer. Closing it wouldn't remove the content or anyone's reputation, but might help guide future visitors in asking more answerable questions.

On the other hand, this sort of question is probably site-relevant enough to justify turning it into a community wiki. That would still allow new and edited content, but would turn off the reputation spigot for what amounts to an opinion poll.

On the third hand—which all project managers need for juggling complex schedules—we can leave it as is and:

- wait for it to self-wikify (assuming Stack Exchange still does that);
- allow opinions to continue generating necro-rep; and
- deal with the spam and low-quality questions this question will attract over time as they appear.

### Restating the Question

What, if anything, ought the community do with [the question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/55/4271) in question?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that many of the questions in our site's early days were asked by the architects of Project Management SE, the people who weren't quite sure what it was or what it was to become. As a result, many of these questions are still sitting around.

One notable answer on this question is [this one, answered by a user who made the question a topic in a blog article she wrote](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/11013/34).  It's possible that others have linked to it as well. Not that this should influence us; it's just something to take note of.

Before doing anything like closing or making it a wiki post, I suspect some editing could be done to clean up the question, such as removing the meta commentary in the last sentence and fixing the spelling and grammar. Then we'd all be able to look at it with a fresh perspective and go from there. We could also look at the answers and see if any of them can be edited as well. Since someone bumped the post, this is a perfect opportunity for some cleanup. :)